# M2 Create configurable product and assign to category but not display product on frontend

Tags: magento2

Links can have a title attribute, which will show up on hover. Title attributes can also be added; they are helpful if the link itself is not descriptive enough to tell users where they're going.

Comment: The title and description don't match and this post seems vague. To answer the problem in the title for those stumbling here. Try reindexing to make sure the product was added to the category in the indexes. `bin/magento indexer:reindex`

Answer (score 0):

First of all go to catalog -> category and make sure that your category is enabled and display mode is set to products only or static block and products

[image]

If these are enabled then please check that the category in which your product is assigned must be assigned in Default Category